# Parameterization using Excel in Selenium Webdriver with C#

Tags: c#, excel, webdriver, parameterization

What C# code should i use for parameterization in webdriver using Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Follow links bellow.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/8ce4dcaf-2a2c-4134-94f4-d48501908446/

http://blog.decaresystems.ie/2008/07/01/data-driven-unit-testing-and-excel-in-visual-studio/